# Having trouble getting DateTime Property in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, datetime

Trying to do a simple LWC that displays relevant fields at the top of an opportunity. But one of the fields is a DateTime field and is giving me some significant problems. When I check in the console, I'm able to see the object and it's fields, but the current format of the get relist() function is getting an error for the 'value' suffix at the end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for the JavaScript.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; 
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    'Opportunity.Name', 
    'Opportunity.Relisting_Status__c', 
    'Opportunity.ReList_Date_TIme__c'
];

// import OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
// import OPPORTUNITY_ORDER_NUMBER_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Relisting_Status__c';
export default class OpportunityNotifications extends LightningElement {
@api recordId; 
relistDateTime; 
@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
opp; 

get name() {
    return this.opp.data.fields.Name.value;
}

get relistStatus() {
    return this.opp.data.fields.Relisting_Status__c.value; 
}

get relist() {
     this.relistDateTime = this.opp.data.fields.Relist_Date_TIme__c.value;

    return this.relistDateTime; 
}




}
```

---------- HTML Component ----------

```
<template>
    <lightning-card class='relist'
        title="Opportunity Relisting"
        icon-name="standard:channel_program_history"
    >
    <template if:true={opp.data}>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <p>YOU WON SOME DATA</p>
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{relistStatus}</p>
        <p><lightning-formatted-date-time value={relist}></lightning-formatted-date-time></p>
    </div>
    </template> 
</template>
```

Comment: could you provide the error message you found in the console log for value of date/time ? also do double check that field Relist_Date_TIme__c is of type date/time

Comment: Hey Shamina, I got it correctly, but I'm not sure why it works this way. Any explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You get the data from `getRecord` wire service in below format:

```
{
  "apiName": "Account",
  "childRelationships": {

  },
  "fields": {
    "Name": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": "University of Boston"
    },
    "POC_Datetime__c": {
      "displayValue": "8/7/2019 8:02 PM",
      "value": "2019-08-08T03:02:37.000Z"
    },
    "Phone": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": "1234567890"
    },
    "Type": {
      "displayValue": "Prospect Translated",
      "value": "Prospect"
    }
  },
  "id": "00128000009j45sAAA",
  "lastModifiedById": "00528000001IIBvAAO",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2019-08-08T07:44:29.000Z",
  "recordTypeInfo": null,
  "systemModstamp": "2019-08-08T07:44:29.000Z"
}
```

> ### Note:
>
> 1. Date/Datetime field has formatted datetime in `displayValue` and actual value in `value` .
> 2. Picklist field **Type** has [translated value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm) in `displayValue` and actual value in `value` .
> 3. Normal field **Phone** has *null* value in `displayValue` and actual value in `value` .

So, for getting properly formatted date you need to use `displayValue` property as bellow from your code:

```
get relist() {
     this.relistDateTime = this.opp.data.fields.Relist_Date_TIme__c.displayValue;
     return this.relistDateTime; 
}
```

This is what is fetched by [getFieldDisplayValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_display_value) service

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We tested this and we were still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works but here is the code that got the date-time field to display correctly...

----------JavaScript----------

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldDisplayValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

/* Importing fields */
import OPPORTUNITY_RELIST_DATE_TIME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.ReList_Date_TIme__c';
import OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import OPPORTUNITY_RELISTING_STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Relisting_Status__c';

const FIELDS = [OPPORTUNITY_RELIST_DATE_TIME_FIELD, 
                OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD, 
                OPPORTUNITY_RELISTING_STATUS_FIELD];

export default class OpportunityNotifications extends LightningElement {
@api recordId; 

@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
opp;

get name() {

    return getFieldDisplayValue(this.opp.data, OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD);
}

get relistStatus() {

    return getFieldDisplayValue(this.opp.data, OPPORTUNITY_RELISTING_STATUS_FIELD); 
}

get relistDate() {

    return getFieldDisplayValue(this.opp.data, OPPORTUNITY_RELIST_DATE_TIME_FIELD);  

}


}
```

----------HTML----------

```
<template>

    <lightning-card 
        title="Opportunity Relisting"
        icon-name="standard:channel_program_history"
    >
    <template if:true={opp.data}>
    <div class="slds-theme_inverse">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p>YOU WON SOME DATA</p>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>{relistStatus}</p>
            <p>{relistDate}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template> 
    </lightning-card> 

</template>
```